# Distance Metric on a Polytope

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, conformal-maps

**Primary Question:** Is it possible to define a distance metric on a polytope (or permutohedron in particular)? I am aware that neither is a smooth, Riemannian manifold; however, computer scientists have employed a [method](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ekmcrane/Projects/HeatMethod/paperCACM.pdf) that solves a Poisson system for the discrete case to calculate the distances between vertices or arbitrary subsets $\gamma$.

**Secondary Question:** One could equip a Riemannian metric $g$ to smooth manifold $\mathcal{M}$ that admits a homeomorphism $f_H: \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{P}$ to a polytope $\mathcal{P}$ satisfying $|f_H(p) - p|^2 < \epsilon$ for $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_+$. I see no reason why it wouldn't be possible to produce a conformal map $f_C : \mathcal{M} \to S^2$ of factor $u$ where $S^2$ is the Riemann sphere with metric $h = e^{2u} g$. Could this map be optimized to minimize the difference between the distance metric on the polytope defined in the primary question and the standard geodesic distance on the Riemann sphere? My desire to achieve a quasi-isometry between $\mathcal{M}$ and $S^2$ is similar to the goal proposed in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681666/can-a-conformal-map-be-turned-into-an-isometry).

Comment: Usually polytopes are embedded in (Euclidean) space, hence one could use ambient metric. But maybe you have something else in mind. In particular do you maybe have in mind the *boundary* of a polytope, which is not a convex set?

Comment: If it's the boundary, just take the shortest PL path. There's a lay-friendly exposition for polyhedra at https://www.quantamagazine.org/the-crooked-geometry-of-round-trips-20210113/